# tesseract training on Windows

Tags: tesseract

I am trying to train tesseract for a new language on Windows 7 using the binaries kindly provided by [UB-Manheim](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract). I am following the training procedure described in [the wiki](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract#run-tesseract-for-training). `text2image` works greatly and generates the files. However, when I run `tesseract ... box.train` I get the following error:

```
read_params_file: Can't open box.train
```

Do the binaries lack something? Is it possible to train tesseract on Windows or should I switch to Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [configs](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/tree/master/tessdata/configs) files under `tessdata\configs` folder.

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't get that "box.train" argument was the path to the config file and not some "option". You've saved me so much time!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to train **tesseract** on **Linux** and use **lang.traineddata** on **Windows**. **I trained** **tesseract 3.04** for persian on linux by following **batch file**(train.sh) and use that far.traineddata on Windows.

```
        for i in `ls -1 *.png`; do j=`echo $i| sed "s/\.png//"`;enter code heretesseract $i $j nobatch box.train; done
        unicharset_extractor *.box
        shapeclustering -F font_properties -U unicharset -O far.unicharset *.tr
        mftraining -F font_properties -U unicharset -O far.unicharset *.tr
        cntraining *.tr
        mv normproto far.normproto; mv inttemp far.inttemp; mv pffmtable far.pffmtable; mv shapetable far.shapetable
        combine_tessdata far.
```